When is it wrong to use んだけど for introducing a subject/adding background information?
These are two corrections (told to remove bolded) from my teacher of some of a short presentation I did on Hokkaido dialect phrases I learned about from an anime:
まず、登場人物によく使われていたのは「したっけ」というものです。標準語では「さようなら」と「そうしたら」という意味になるそうです。例を挙げると、「したっけね〜！」とかいうと「じゃあ、またね～！」という意味です。しかし、私の印象なんですけど、そのアニメを見ている間には「じゃあ、また」より「したっけ」のほうがうれしいというかあの子供たちは仲がいいかもねという感じがしました。
最後に、文末につけた「べ」というのを紹介します。厳密に言えば、これは北海道だけで使われているわけじゃないみたいなんですけど、とても有名な表現で入れたかったんです。
I was told by her that when there is many んですs it makes the sentence/assertion a bit strong (no more info than that). I am not sure why these usages are incorrect however, because I remember learning that んだけど and its various forms can be used to either bring up a subject or say something with a bit of hesitation. Whatever the case may be I feel like I hear stuff like 僕の考えなんだけど many times in podcasts when the speaker is bringing up their thoughts and I wonder why these usages are incorrect in comparison.

It's perfectly fine to either keep or remove these なん, especially in speech. There is no strong reason to remove them. It's true that you should not use なん excessively to avoid sounding repetitive, but how much is too much is a very subjective matter.
Still, なん can give off a colloquial or informal impression, and your text somewhat looks like a transcribed oral interview. If you want a more formal tone, it may be better to reduce the number of なん a bit and say 私の印象ですが and 北海道だけで使われているわけではないようですが, respectively.
